# Having a CecBenchmark error while running a .ipynb code?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm encountering a TypeError in my Python code while trying to initialize an object from the CecBenchmark class.

```
Getting this error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-225488b52195> in <cell line: 30>()
     28 rows=30 # pop size
     29 prob_no=15 # engineering problem no or benchmark function no
---> 30 out = BF(prob_no)  # Get object contain information about problems
     31 D, g, h, xmin, xmax = out["D"], out["g"], out["h"], out["xmin"], out["xmax"]
     32 dim=D

TypeError: CecBenchmark.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```